# How did Bob Vaughn's handwriting match with the handwriting in the Zodiac letters?

Tags: plot-explanation, zodiac

The crime thriller film Zodiac left too many unanswered questions for us. One of them is the similarity between the handwriting of Bob Vaughn (who used to work with Rick Marshall, one of the Zodiac suspects) and the handwriting in the Zodiac letters. Since Arthur Lieh was considered to be the real Zodiac killer, this handwriting mystery remained unsolved as Bob Vaughn had nothing to do with Arthur Lieh (apparently). Does there exist an explanation? I will be delighted to have one.

Comment: Handwriting is not an exact science seems the most likely reason. People will see what they want to see.

Comment: Explanation to what ? It's clearly shown in movie that the handwriting was similar and letter "K" was unmatched on the poster.

Comment: But there was something different in the behaviour of Bob Vaughn which frightened Garysmith. That's why I asked.

Comment: Now you are referring to behaviour which has nothing to do with your question.